# the conditional gradient methodo

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimal-control, gradient-descent

I'm reading the book of "optimal control of partial differential equations by Fredi Troltizsch". In chapter two page 92 I have a problem with the conditional gradient method. What is the convergence rate of the conditional gradient method?